# Unresolved External between static library projects in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I've a visual studio solution structured like this:

*Project A (static Library)

*Project B (static Library)

*Testing project (exe)

Project B references project A regularly, and the testing project uses both. Recently, I've added some new functions to project A, but trying to use the new functions in project B causes an unresolved external when building the testing project. I've checked and it only happens in one class (Model.cpp), I can successfully use new functions from other classes in project B. What could be causing project b to trip up on one class from A, but not any others? I've done multiple rebuilds, cleans etc on all projects
Thanks

Comment: So you cannot use any functions from that one class (Model.cpp) at all? Then it seems that class is not linked into the libraries and/or the testing application. You may be able to check this with [Dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I can create and use variables in an instance of that class. So I can do ```Model * m = new Model()``` and access ```m.memberVar```. But I can't use any methods pertaining to ```Model```. Very strange. I'll have a look at dumpbin now

Comment: What exactly should I be looking for with dumpbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The methods in question all used classes/structures from the glm maths library. In some files I was defining some stuff for the library, but in the Model.h I wasn't. I'm going to make a common import for glm to make sure every file that uses it has the correct definitions.